# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'labels' referenced before assignment white training for object detection using torch and yolov3

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, torch, yolo

I'm training on custom objects for object detection by using yolo-v3 and PyTorch . labeling and every other task completed. while run the train command I'm getting the following error

```
(base) C:\Users\murali\Desktop\yolov3>python train.py --data coco.data --cfg cfg/yolov3.cfg
Namespace(accumulate=2, adam=False, arc='defaultpw', batch_size=32, bucket='', cache_images=False, cfg='cfg/yolov3.cfg', data='coco.data', device='', epochs=273, evolve=False, img_size=416, img_weights=False, multi_scale=False, name='', nosave=False, notest=False, prebias=False, rect=False, resume=False, transfer=False, var=None, weights='')
Using CPU

WARNING:root:This caffe2 python run does not have GPU support. Will run in CPU only mode.
Reading labels (357 found, 0 missing, 4 empty for 361 images): 100%|███████████████| 361/361 [00:00<00:00, 6489.34it/s]
Model Summary: 222 layers, 6.19491e+07 parameters, 6.19491e+07 gradients
Starting training for 273 epochs...

 Epoch   gpu_mem      GIoU       obj       cls     total   targets  img_size

Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
0%| | 0/12 [00:00<?, ?it/s]Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 1 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Corrupt JPEG data: 2 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 426, in
train() # train normally
File "train.py", line 235, in train
for i, (imgs, targets, paths, _) in pbar: # batch -------------------------------------------------------------
File "C:\Users\murali\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tqdm_tqdm.py", line 1005, in iter
for obj in iterable:
File "C:\Users\murali\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 819, in next
return self._process_data(data)
File "C:\Users\murali\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 846, in _process_data
data.reraise()
File "C:\Users\murali\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch_utils.py", line 369, in reraise
raise self.exc_type(msg)
UnboundLocalError: Caught UnboundLocalError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\murali\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data_utils\worker.py", line 178, in _worker_loop
data = fetcher.fetch(index)
File "C:\Users\murali\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data_utils\fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
File "C:\Users\murali\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data_utils\fetch.py", line 44, in
data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
File "C:\Users\murali\Desktop\yolov3\utils\datasets.py", line 416, in getitem
img, labels = load_mosaic(self, index)
File "C:\Users\murali\Desktop\yolov3\utils\datasets.py", line 590, in load_mosaic
labels4.append(labels)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'labels' referenced before assignment
```

The lines mentioned the error is following two part of code in 
*dataset.py*

416 line is in following code

> ```
>     if mosaic:
>         # Load mosaic
>     img, labels = load_mosaic(self, index)
>         h, w, _ = img.shape
> ```

590 line in the following code (labels4.append(labels))

> ```
>     # Load labels
>     label_path = self.label_files[index]
>     if os.path.isfile(label_path):
>         x = self.labels[index]
>         if x is None:  # labels not preloaded
>             with open(label_path, 'r') as f:
>                 x = np.array([x.split() for x in f.read().splitlines()], dtype=np.float32)
>
>         if x.size > 0:
>             # Normalized xywh to pixel xyxy format
>             labels = x.copy()
>             labels[:, 1] = w * (x[:, 1] - x[:, 3] / 2) + padw
>             labels[:, 2] = h * (x[:, 2] - x[:, 4] / 2) + padh
>             labels[:, 3] = w * (x[:, 1] + x[:, 3] / 2) + padw
>             labels[:, 4] = h * (x[:, 2] + x[:, 4] / 2) + padh
>
>         labels4.append(labels)
> labels4 = np.concatenate(labels4, 0)
> ```

How to solve this?

The full code is [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3/blob/master/utils/datasets.py)

`

Comment: Well, what do you want to happen if `x.size <= 0`?

Comment: Are you sure about the indentation of the block of code after Line 416?

Comment: I used the code from [here] (https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3/blob/master/utils/datasets.py)

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of one or more label files will be empty. So check if your train or test dataset contains empty label files. If it contains then delete it and create new label files for the same with annotation values. you can use the following code to find if the label files are empty or not.

```
import os
label_paths =''
labels = os.listdir(label_paths)

for label_file in labels:
    label_file_with_path = label_paths + label_file
    size_of_label_file = os.path.getsize(label_file_with_path)
    if size_of_label_file == 0:
       print('Empty label file :', label_file)
```

Refer [this link](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov3/issues/548)